# Eu fêcho ou eu fécho, qual a pronuncia correta?

Tags: pronúncia

O verbo "fechar", dependendo da conjugação, dever ser pronunciado com a vogal (ê) fechada ou aberta (é).

> Eu fêcho a porta.
>   ou
>   Eu fécho a porta.

Eu fêcho ou eu fécho, qual a pronuncia correta?

Existe alguma diferença entre ptPT e ptBR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Brasil, o substantivo "fecho" é sempre pronunciado com a vogal tônica fechada, em geral /'fe.ʃu/. Pode ser que em São Paulo capital e sua área de influência se pronuncie também /'fej.ʃu/. Pelo que eu entendo, a pronúncia em Portugal é também sempre fechada, porém há mais alófones: /'fej.ʃu/, /'fɐj.ʃu/, /'fe.ʃu/ e /'fɐ.ʃu/. Corrijam-me os portugueses que aqui postam.

No Brasil, "fecho", primeira pessoa do presente do indicativo - e todas as formas rizotônicas do verbo "fechar" - é sempre ou quase sempre pronunciada com a vogal tônica aberta: /'fɛ.ʃu/ (Talvez /'fɛ:.ʃu/ nos mesmos lugares onde o substantivo é /'fej.ʃu/. "Quase sempre", a ponto de que a pronúncia com a vogal tônica fechada provoca estranheza, com o falante que a utiliza sendo percebido como estrangeiro ou como pedante.

Já as formas arrizotônicas do mesmo verbo se pronunciam, no Brasil, com a vogal sempre fechada, /fe.'ʃaɾ/, com a exceção do Recife e sua área de influência, onde é /fɛ'ʃaɾ/, e talvez /fɨ.'ʃaɾ/ no litoral de Santa Catarina e /fej.'ʃaɾ/ em São Paulo (desconsiderando aqui a pronúncia do /ɾ/ final, que pode ser pronunciado de muitas formas diferentes, incluindo a elisão).

Comment: no Rio deve ser fêzchar

Comment: Não é, mas festa é /'fɛjʃ.tɐ/.

Answer (score 2):

A pronúncia é diferente entre PT-PT e PT-BR. E pode não existir uma forma universalmente aceite, mesmo em cada caso.

O dicionário fonético de portal da língua portuguese especifica [fecho](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/%3E?action=fonetica&region=lbx&act=details&id=14406) com a pronúncia **fˈɐ.ʃu** (aproximadamente como se fosse "fâcho"), isto para o nome e não a forma verbal. Contudo, a palavra é tipicamente homónima. Também em algumas regiões de Portugal a pronúncia tende para **fˈɐj.ʃu** ou até mesmo **fˈej.ʃu** , ou seja, fazendo o "ã" transitar suavemente para um "i", algo parecido com "fãicho" ou "feicho".

No Brasil, a pronúncia indicada no dicionário já é **fˈe.ʃu**, como se fosse "fêcho". Por outro lado, muitas pessoas no país pronunciam **fˈɛ.ʃu** ("fécho").

Os dicionários fonéticos não costumam considerar formas verbais, o que torna esta matéria mais complicada de definir. Contudo, o emprego de uma das pronúncias acima será mais que suficiente para ser entendido na prática.

Comment: A tua resposta está corretíssima. Veja [Fecho no Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fecho): fe·cho |â| ou |ê|. Em portugal é uma grafia tendendo ao A.

Comment: em pt-BR "fêcho" é o fecho da porta, e "fécho' é o verbo "eu fecho a porta", ficaria "Eu fécho o fêcho da porta"

Comment: E_net4, e @EduardoFernandes vocês estão a ver a pronúncia do substantivo *fecho* e não do forma verbal.

Comment: Not! Veja o link que eu coloquei no comentário: "Ferrolho ou aldraba de porta. 2. Qualquer peça ou objecto que serve para fechar ou cerrar."

Comment: @EduardoFernandes Precisamente, isso é um substantivo. Aliás, está  escrito no Priberam, «substantivo masculino». A pergunta é sobre a forma verbal: «eu fêcho a porta ou eu fécho a porta» (não *o fecho da porta*). (Precisas de pôr um «@jacinto» se quiseres que eu seja notificado dos teus comentários).

Comment: Em pt-BR, eu sempre ouvi e pronunciei "eu fecho, tu fechas e ele fecha"  rimando com "flecha" e não com "queixa".

Comment: @Centaurus Flecha pronuncia-se 
flˈɛ.ʃɐ, com um fonema diferente no "e". Quanto mais, poderá haver uma confusão de sotaques.

Comment: Eu digo *eu fécho, tu féchas*, tal como o @Centaurus , e *um fêcho*. Não serei o único em Portugal. Esta diferença entre verbo e substantivo é relativamente comum (*eu péso, um pêso*). O link na pergunta, segundo o que lá está,  indica a pronúncia de Lisboa, e é um recurso em teste. Vários dicionários portugueses indicam para o substantivo *fecho* a pronúncia *fâcho, fâicho* e *fêcho*. Mas a pergunta é apenas sobre a forma verbal e não sobre o substantivo.

Comment: @Jacinto com todo o respeito, isso parece-me ser um regionalismo, e é de duvidar que haja um dicionário fonético com todos os regionalismos contemplados. É uma área bem mais incerta, portanto. A minha resposta considera as situações mais comuns.

Comment: @E_net4  Discordo peremptoriamente (ou perentoriamente como diriam nossos amigos de ultramar).  Não preciso procurar uma estatística a respeito: todas as pessoas que eu conheço aqui no Rio de Janeiro pronunciam "eu fecho" com o "e" bem aberto como em "flecha".

Comment: E_net4, a tua resposta (de que gosto) não considera as situações «mais comuns» - quando muito considera as mais normativas. Se morasses onde mora o @Jacinto, as situações mais comuns seriam outras. Se morasses *no Puôrto*, as situações mais comuns seriam ainda outras.

Comment: @E_net4, eis uma possível fonte acerca de pronúncias: http://pt.forvo.com/word/fecho

Comment: Olha, eu sou brasileiro, vivo no Brasil praticamente desde que nasci, e já convivi com gente de todas as regiões e da maioria dos estados. Há algumas pouquíssimas pessoas que pronunciam "eu *fêcho* a porta"; de uma maneira geral, são também aquelas que dizem "hoje *são* 24 de agosto". Creio que 99,99% das pessoas dizem "eu *fécho* a porta".

Comment: @LuísHenrique Não se esqueçam que não é isso o que está estabelecido nos dicionários fonéticos até agora apresentados. Das duas uma, ou 99.99% dos brasileiros não seguem a suposta norma oficial, ou então a veracidade destas fontes está a ser contestada.

Comment: @ANeves com certeza, e agradeço a desambiguação e fonte adicional. Não sou do Porto, mas sou de um concelho com pronúncia do norte.

Comment: @E_net4 - Ou, ainda, a "norma oficial" está obsoleta.

Comment: @E_net4 o site de pronúncias nem diferencia substantivo do verbo.Veja a moça do google pronunciando [Google Tradutor](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/eu%20fecho%20a%20porta)

Comment: @LuísHenrique e E_net4: **Nenhum** dicionário fonético até agora apresentado dá a pronúncia da forma verbal; apenas dão a do substantivo. É muito comum a diferença ***ê*** no substantivo vs. ***é*** na forma verbal: *eu coméço/o comêço, eu régo/o rêgo, eu sélo/o sêlo, eu aperto/o apêrto, eu péso/o pêso*, etc.

Comment: @Jacinto aqui no norte dizemos "feicho".

Comment: @Jacinto Não me parece que "fêcho" seja possível em Lisboa, quer para o nome ou para o verbo. Para o verbo, pelo menos, "fâ(i)cho" é o mais comum, mas "fécho" também se ouve muito, talvez mais nas pessoas mais velhas.

Comment: @Artefacto Concordo. Exceto para pessoas como eu que não são originalmente de Lisboa, claro. Inclino-me a pensar que a pronúncia *um fêcho/eu fécho* ocorra na área onde tradicionalmente o *ei* era pronunciado ***ê*** -- sul menos Lisboa.

Comment: @Artefacto E tu achas que a pronúncia /fˈɐ.ʃu/ ( *fâcho*) é comum em Lisboa para o nome ou verbo?  Não me lembro de ter ouvido, e acho que se tivesse ouvido notaria.

Answer (score 0):

A mais consensual é "fêcho", sendo que em Portugal o "ê" tonico antes de CH é pronunciado como ditongo, ou seja, /ˈfɐj.ʃu/.